# Please merge the ms-access tag into microsoft-access on Super User

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

On Super User, [microsoft-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-access) has 13 questions while [ms-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) has 6. No questions have both tags.

Also, [two](https://superuser.com/questions/46161/ms-access-template-where-to-find-the-vb-code) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/47302/migrating-ms-access-2003-to-ms-access-2007) are tagged 'access' when one of the above would be more appropriate ([access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access) is being used for questions about, well, accessing things).

I realize this is a small enough retag that a normal user could do it, but I don't have enough rep to do it myself.

Answer (score 5):

Done. All **[ms-access]** changed to **[microsoft-access]** on SU.

There was only one question I saw with **[access]** that needed to be changed.

Comment: The other [access] question was http://superuser.com/questions/46161/ms-access-template-where-to-find-the-vb-code.

Comment: Status complete. ;)

Comment: Thanks; here's 25 points for your trouble. :)